# aggregate date for last 7 days python

Tags: python, pandas, date, grouping

I have dataset like that:

```
 app id geo  date        count
    90  NO  2018-09-04  27.31019
    66  HK  2018-06-10  0.187075    
    80  QA  2018-04-22  5.826288    
    85  MA  2018-10-11  1.200000    
    80  BR  2018-09-14  68.390496
```

I am trying to get last 7 and 3 days data for each date

```
 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')
    df = df.groupby(['geo','app_id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W')]) . 
   ['count'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('date')
```

Since weekly frequency is calculated from a particular week day (Sunday in this case) I don't have 7 day gap.

Are there any options to aggregate data for a given number of days?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You can use these as frequencies http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Comment: You can add week coulumn using [dt.week](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.Series.dt.week.html) and group by it.